# Compile error: Can't find project or library

Tags: excel, vba, dll, reference, compatibility

I got a excel document from someone which was created by another person few years ago with excel 2003. I try to open and run his code and I get the error: Compile error: Can't find project or library.

I looked in the refence and this is what is written : Missing: 12 authorization control 1.0 type library.

Things I tried:

- So I downloaded the dll and added it to the path, but this did not solve the problem.
- I've unchecked this missing reference from the options, this time the code did run.

But it did not work as supposed to. The generate button is supposed to generate a table inside a word document at a bookmark(also inside a .c file). The word document **is indeed** modified when I click the generate button, but the added row in the sheet `io_list` is not added to the word file.

Is the cause of this problem  the missing dll?

Comment: Did you **register** the dll?

Answer (score 0):

I was a missing reference.

Check this box `Microsoft office 14 authorizaiton Controle 1.0 ...`

instead and it will work.